# Export rootfs or tmpfs

Tags: linux, mount, nfs

Is it possible to export (for nfs mounting) tmpfs or rootfs directories?
I have many linux nodes which are booted into a ram based filesystem with just rootfs and tmpfs. I want each node to see some files in the other nodes, so I am trying to export some directory and trying to mount on another node.
I see the following error in /var/log/messages of the nfs server -
rpc.mountd: getfh failed: No such file or directory

I have read that one cannot export tmpfs. Is the same true for rootfs? What options do I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rootfs` **is** `ramfs` or `tmpfs`, depending on kernel version and configuration.

`ramfs` can't be exported over NFS.  However, exporting `tmpfs` over NFS works for me, and should: it's been in mainline for years.  [91828a405ae454a9503c41a7744f6ff877a80714](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=commit;h=91828a405ae454a9503c41a7744f6ff877a80714).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a programming question and really belongs somewhere else (like serverfault.com as soon as Jeff throws the switch), but googling "linux nfs root" turns up the [following](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/NFS-Root.html) which should help you get started.